# How to access mysql command line on Mac via Xamp

Tags: mysql

How do I access this on a mac? I cannot seem to find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have MAMP, and for that its located at :-
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql

i am assuming XAMP is something similar..

Answer (score 0):

Can you open a terminal and then:

```
mysql -u username -p database_to_use
```